# React.js app is returning a 403 (forbidden) error code on axios get call

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios, next.js, dotenv

Problem: 
I'm implementing the stormglass.io api on my react app.  I make the api call using axios.  When I make the api call with the api key included in the header it works fine, but when I try to store the api keys in a .env file (for security reasons), I get a 403 (forbidden) code when I make the api call.

Expected Result: 
I should be getting my api response data, but for some reason the api key isn't being accepted when it's stored in the .env file.

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next dev
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
info  - Loaded env from /home/dill5446/git_workspace/pdill.dev/pdill.dev/.env
event - compiled successfully
```

```
xhr.js?b50d:177 GET https://api.stormglass.io/v2/weather/point?lat=21.3&lng=-157.8&params=secondarySwellDirection,secondarySwellHeight,secondarySwellPeriod,windWaveDirection,windWaveHeight,windWavePeriod,swellDirection,swellHeight,swellPeriod,waveDirection,waveHeight,wavePeriod,windDirection,windSpeed,gust,waterTemperature,currentDirection,currentSpeed,cloudCover,airTemperature 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

Solutions that I've tried: 
I tried adding a 'dotenv' package that I read about as a possible solution.  I also added a 'dotenv-webpack' dependency that I read about.  I added the following code to my next.config.js (for the record, I'm not super experienced using the config files):

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)
      })
    )
    return config
  }
}

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env', // load this now instead of the ones in '.env'
      safe: true, // load '.env.example' to verify the '.env' variables are all set. Can also be a string to a different file.
      allowEmptyValues: true, // allow empty variables (e.g. `FOO=`) (treat it as empty string, rather than missing)
      systemvars: true, // load all the predefined 'process.env' variables which will trump anything local per dotenv specs.
      silent: true, // hide any errors
      defaults: false // load '.env.defaults' as the default values if empty.
    })
  ]
}
```

The api call looks like this (shortened):

```
  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  const apiCall = () => {
    Axios.all([
      Axios.get(`https://api.stormglass.io/v2/weather/point?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&params=${params}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${API_KEY}`
        }
      }
      ),
      Axios.get(`https://api.stormglass.io/v2/tide/extremes/point?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&start=${today.toISOString()}&end=${tenDaysOut.toISOString()}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${API_KEY}`
        }
      })
    ])
      .then(async (response) => await setData(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }
```

Comment: Next.js has built-in support for .env files. I'd recommend you have a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables.

Comment: @juliomalves - Thank you for the suggestion!  That fixed it.  I was using 'REACT_APP_' as the base for my key name and I should have been using 'NEXT_PUBLIC_'